# Access denied from apt in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt

I'm actually using Linux Mint 18.04 on a 32-bit system, with an old computer, recently in dual-boot with Windows Vista. In the first times, I was able to download and install applications through terminal (with Konsole). But I come up with some problems. The first one is that I get "access denied" when I enter a command which needs apt file.

```
[sudo] password for ezer: 
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/apt: Permission denied
Hangup
ezer@admin-mintpower ~ $ su
Password: 
admin-mintpower ezer # sudo apt purge python2.x-minimal
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/apt: Permission denied
Hangup
```

I have tried to change owner but it doesn't worked.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

After you are in super user/root mode (su), is there still a need to use sudo?  Try dropping the sudo while you are in root. There might be an issue with your sudoers file.

Try the first answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/65048/permission-denied-for-user-with-sudo-privileges) for troubleshooting steps for the sudo issue.